# Cannot add custom css in site

Tags: customization, css

I am trying to add custom css in my wordpress site. It is possible until before 2 days. From yesterday I couldn't update the css. Instead it is showing some error. So I have decide to edit directly in the database, because the site live and I can't waste time. I have updated the css in `wp_post` table but no change. Is there any other option?

Comment: "some error". What error?

Comment: Looks like something’s gone wrong. Wait a couple seconds, and then try again.